# Twitter Bootstrap forms in ASP.Net webforms?

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, webforms

Trying to set up some forms on an ASP.Net webforms application and Twitter Bootstrap is *mostly* proving very helpful.

Except.... For some of them I'd really rather be able to use form styles other than the default, which requires me to set a class name on the parent form. Which, if I ever knew how to access it in Webforms I've completely forgotten now.

Is there a way to do this that anyone can point me to? Thanks :-)

Answer (score 3):

To add any attribute that is not available as a property in the control you can do this:

```
Form.Attributes.Add("class", "any_css_to_the_form");
```